# Why does Vanellope continue to glitch?

Tags: wreck-it-ralph

In the film, Vanellope is a 'glitch', but...

> ... she's only a glitch because Turbo rewrote her code...

...which should have been 'fixed' on crossing the finish line.

**Why is she still a glitch?**

Answer (score 24):

The "glitch" was actually a legitimate in-game power that Vannelope possessed. It was only because the Sugarlanders had been 'memory wiped' that they didn't remember it (and hence made fun of her for it).

Note that final arcade scene at the end of the film, we see the young racer activate Vannelope's glitch using the horn button. At the top of the screen, one pink diamond is removed to indicate that a special ability has been used. Presumably each of the other drivers also have in-game abilities.

[image]

And confirmed in [Ralph Breaks the Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Breaks_the_Internet)

> **Girl:** Pick Vanellope, Bonny, **she's got the best superpower!**
>
> **Bonny:** **Yeah, the glitch!**

Comment: hmm, interesting. Any clips or screenshots?

Comment: It's been a while, but I seem to remember some mention in the epilogue that she kept the glitch ability for unknown reasons, and it became her in-game special.

Comment: Yeah cause if it waa an ability she just naturaly had she would be able to leave the game. I think it just became an ability after.

Comment: **Wreck-it Ralph 2 spoiler alert** The virus designed to look for and propagate program bugs in Ralph Breaks the Internet detected Vanellope's glitch. Which suggests that this was, in fact, a glitch, rather than a legitimate power she was programmed with from the get-go.

Comment: @MishaR - it's equally likely that it's reading her as glitchy because a) Turbo pulled all of her wires or b) because her special power is to "glitch".

Comment: No, I don't think it's equally likely.  I don't think the wire-pulling was addressed in any negative way afterwards, that seems like your own narrative. As for her special power - if it were, in fact, legitimate programming, then it wouldn't be a bug.  Unless we preemptively accept that her glitch definitely wasn't a bug, then the Ralph2 virus very much suggests that it was.

Comment: @MishaR - Her personality is deeply warped. She goes Turbo and game-jumps. That doesn't seem like the act of a well-programmed piece of software

Comment: Yes, and yet only the glitch part of her character was detected and propagated.

Comment: @MishaR - And yet all signs point to her glitch being a legitimate in-game device, not least the fact that she can leave her game after she's repaired.

Comment: @MishaR The official 'Ralph Breaks the Internet' Junior novel backs this up. *“Pick Vanellope,” Nafisa said. “She’s got the best super power.” “Yeah, the glitch,” said Swati. “I love her.”* - The clear implication is that all of the drivers have powers and hers is the best.

Comment: @MishaR - lol. It's not picking up on her glitch as the insecurity, it's picking up on her *personality* insecurity - "*While he sat alone, the virus worm squirmed through the firewall hole and exited Slaughter Race. **Ralph had never felt so low. Even though Vanellope was gone, he spoke out loud as if she were there. “Vanellope, what am I supposed to do? What do I do?” It quickly picked up on Ralph, finding him to be one hundred percent insecure.** Without anyone noticing, it copied Ralph’s insecurity . . . and began to distribute it all over the Internet.*"